# Loop table row by condition in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have this table, where the icons in the "Status" column are "SVG" elements, what I want is to go through the table and when it finds the first "SVG" element with attribute '[aria-label="It is not paid" ]' take the value of "Name" from the same row and assign it to a variable. Is it possible?

[image: Table]

At this moment I can get the first element, but I haven't been able to find a reference for what I need.

cy.get('[aria-label="It is not payed"]').first().click({force:true});

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the table?

Answer (score 2):

To implement a looping solution, use the `.each()` command.

```js
cy.get('table tbody tr td svg[aria-label="It is not paid"]')
  .each($svg => {
    $svg.click()
  })
```

---

**Potential hazards**

Since `svg.click()` is an action, it may cause the web page to re-write the table.

If it rewrites the **whole table**, this will crash after the first item because the `cy.get('table tbody tr')` becomes invalid after a rewrite.

To solve it, use the `index` parameter to repeat the query *inside* the loop. This ensures a up-to-date value even when the page has been refreshed.

```js
cy.get('table tbody tr td svg[aria-label="It is not paid"]')
  .each((_, index) => {
    cy.get('table tbody tr td svg[aria-label="It is not paid"]')
      .eq(index)
      .click()
  })
```

---

**Best practice**

Best practice is actually to set up the test conditions exactly.

For example, if I set up the table like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jose</td>
      <td>jose</td>
      <td>
        <svg aria-label="It is not paid"></svg>
      </td>
      <td>sap</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Luis</td>
      <td>luis</td>
      <td>
        <svg aria-label="It is paid"></svg>
      </td>
      <td>sap</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Arnoldo</td>
      <td>arnoldo</td>
      <td>
        <svg aria-label="It is not paid"></svg>
      </td>
      <td>sap</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

then I can confirm each row independently in the test

```js
// First row
cy.get('table tbody tr').eq(0)
  .find('svg').should('have.attr', 'aria-label', 'It is not paid')

cy.get('table tbody tr').eq(0).find('svg').click()

cy.get('table tbody tr').eq(0)
  .find('svg').should('have.attr', 'aria-label', 'It is paid')

// Second row
cy.get('table tbody tr').eq(1)
  .find('svg').should('have.attr', 'aria-label', 'It is paid')
```